Function related to length of group presentations: is it computable?
(This question comes from a friend who works in sofic group theory.)
Consider the function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, defined, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, by putting $f(n)$ to be the largest cardinal of a finite group which has at least one presentation of length at most $n$ (I think any "natural" definition of length works.)
Is $f$ computable? If yes, is there a simple description of it? If not, is it "equivalent" to the busy beaver function or is it of higher growth?

Small note: I suspect it is not computable, but at least the obvious analogue of the proof of uncomputability of the Busy Beaver function fails here. The difference is that while it is decidable if a Turing machine halts in at most $n$ steps for any fixed $n$, it is undecidable whether a group has at most $n$ elements by Adian-Rabin.

Very nice question! It would suffice for us to provide, for any Turing machine program $p$, a group presentation (of about the same size as $p$), which presented a group at least as large as the running time of $p$, if it halts, otherwise infinite. If that were possible, then your function would essentially majorize the busy beaver function. But is this possible?

@JoelDavidHamkins: Something like this should be possible. For instance, there is a recursive sequence of finite presentations $H_n$ such that $|H_n|$ is either infinite or $n$, and the set of $n$ for which $|H_n|$ is finite is r.e. but not recursive. (And probably we could also make $|H_n|$ the running time of the $n$th Turing machine.) The idea is simple. The Adyan--Rabin theorem produces a sequence of presentations for groups $G_n$ such that ${G_n\cong 1}$ is r.e. but not recursive. Now set $H_n=C_n\times (G_n*G_n)$.

From a group-theory perspective, I don't see how to conclude from there. If $f$ were computable then we would get an explicit finite list of candidate cyclic groups for $H_n$, but that buys me nothing: taking the abelianisation always tells me exactly which finite cyclic group $H_n$ is, if it is one. But perhaps I am missing something.

Oh, perhaps the problem is that we can't set $H_n$ to be the running time of the $n$th Turing machine $T_n$, because that number is only finite when $T_n$ halts, i.e. when $G_n\cong 1$.

@HJRW I don't think the $C_n\times(G_n*G_n)$ presentation idea is going to work, since the $C_n$ factor is what makes it size $n$, but we need this to be the (unknown) running time at the time we form the presentation. The size of the program $p$ is going to be typically far smaller than the running time, and we can't afford to find out what the running time is, since we don't know whether it halts.

What we need to do is to form the presentation directly from the program, in such a manner that produces a group whose size is related to the running time, whether this is finite or infinite. The examples I know have the feature that a halting computation causes a big collapse in the group; but perhaps the experts have other examples with the required feature.

Does "the sum of word length of relators" qualify as acceptable "length"?

@YCor yes, it does.

Being finite is semi-decidable but not decidable from finite presentations.
Conjecture: finiteness remains undecidable for groups given by finite presentations together with a solution to the word problem.
If this conjecture is true, then the function f given in the question is not computable.
In particular, proving that for some family of finitely presented groups with uniformly solvable word problem finiteness is not decidable is sufficient to show that f cannot be bounded by a computable function. But I am not aware of any construction doing this and I think the problem is very open.

@E.Rauzy I wouldn't bet money on that conjecture being true. It's decidable, for example, whether a finitely presented group with decidable word problem is free or not.

@Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda Well I don't have very good arguments either. But I don't think that something similar to the Groves-Wilton Theorem on recognizing free groups can be used for finite groups because of Makanin (universal theory of free groups is decidable) vs Slobodskoi (universal theory of finite groups is undecidable).
